# R: Adding Labels to a Point on a Scatterplot

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I would like to make a scatterplot using the plotly library and add labels to each of the points.

Here is the data I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(ggrepel)

a = rnorm(10,100,100)
b = rnorm(10,100,100)

# imagine that the labels are only available for some of the points
labels = c("FKUEV3116M", "PUGOV5350W", "ILRBL1594B", "ZCWUS4589U", "ZRWJN8129J", 
"FYNMZ0695L", "LTMGK4676V", NA, NA, NA)

my_data = data.frame(a,b, labels)
```

I know how to do this using ggplot2 and then convert the result into a plotly object:

```
d = ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a, y=b)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text(label=labels, position=position_jitter(width=1,height=1))

ggplotly(d)
```

**But is it possible to do this using the plotly library itself and adding "jitter" to the labels?** I tried the following code and it is not working:

```
d = ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a, y=b)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(label=labels) + 
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
    geom_text(position = position_jitter(seed = 1))

ggplotly(d)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Note:** Alternate Way I Tried:

```
# note: unfortunately, this does not support the "ggrepel" function 
d = ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a, y=b)) +
    geom_point()  +   geom_text_repel(aes(x = a, 
                                                    y = b, 
                                                    label = labels))
```

Answer (score 3):

This would add the jitter in to the labels and propagate to the `plotly` plot.  You can change the height and width to give more or less random variation in the labels.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
a = rnorm(10,100,100)
b = rnorm(10,100,100)

# imagine that the labels are only available for some of the points
labels = c("FKUEV3116M", "PUGOV5350W", "ILRBL1594B", "ZCWUS4589U", "ZRWJN8129J", 
           "FYNMZ0695L", "LTMGK4676V", NA, NA, NA)

my_data = data.frame(a,b, labels)

d = ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a, y=b)) +
     geom_point() + 
     geom_text(aes(label=labels), position=position_jitter(15, 15, seed=1))
ggplotly(d)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

An alternative option would be to put the label in the tooltip.  You could then just plot the points and let viewers hover over the points to identify the labels.

```r
  my_data <- my_data %>% 
    mutate(txt = paste0("A: ", round(a, 3), 
                        "\nB: ", round(b, 3), 
                        "\nLabel: ", labels))
  d = ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a, y=b, text=txt)) +
       geom_point() 
       
  ggplotly(d, tooltip="text")
```

Answer (score 1):

In `plotly` you can use the argument `text` and `add_markers` with `add_text` like this:

```r
library(plotly)

a = rnorm(10,100,100)
b = rnorm(10,100,100)

# imagine that the labels are only available for some of the points
labels = c("FKUEV3116M", "PUGOV5350W", "ILRBL1594B", "ZCWUS4589U", "ZRWJN8129J", 
           "FYNMZ0695L", "LTMGK4676V", NA, NA, NA)

my_data = data.frame(a,b, labels)

plot_ly(data = my_data, x= ~a, y = ~b, text = ~labels) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  add_text(textposition = "top right") %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>